# How to Auto discovery Two or More Application Using Hazelcast in Docker?

Tags: docker, hazelcast, autodiscovery

I have an application that uses hazelcast. I am running two  containers related to this application in docker emvironment. The configuration of hazelcast is same(group name, password, multicast or tcp-ip for network join) However, they cannot see each other and cannot create cluster group. Each of them create its own cluster.

The question is that:

- How should I define multicast network for docker in hazelcast.xml?
  —-For example, defining just multicast group and port did not work for me.(But it was working when two virtual machines were used)
- When I tried network configuration for tcp-ip enabled and assigned docker defined ip addresses as members in hazelcast.xml, it also did not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0/deploy/installing-using-docker) and [this](https://hazelcast.com/blog/configuring-hazelcast-in-non-orchestrated-docker-environments/) should get you going.

One thing to pay attention to is the IP address (and the flag `hazelcast.local.publicAddress`).
On Docker, inside the container it will see a specific IP address but from outside the container it will be a different IP address.

Comment: Thank you so much. Members successfully joined into the cluster.